# ServiceBusExplorer is not showing the topics

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, service-bus-explorer

I am using the [ServiceBusExplorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) 5.0.18 version. I am connecting to a service bus by using its connection string. It's not showing the topics now. It was working fine before but suddenly stopped showing the topics now. It's working fine for the other service bus.
What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Cross posted from [GitHub(https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues/766). Is it working correctly with another ASB namespace? Have you checked the settings to verify topics are not excluded?

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue? @Vivek Nuna

Comment: @Jahnavi it’s intermittent, sometimes i see this sometimes not

Answer (score 0):

Service bus explorer tool has some challenges/issues in recent operational work scenarios. Hence, they have offered `service bus explorer` option directly in the portal.

To access `service bus explorer`, go to your `service bus namespace >> queues or topics` whichever is required for your operations. Once it is done, select a specific queue and you will be able to view it as shown below.

[image]

*If you still want to use the service bus explorer tool, use the latest version of the tool releases and try disconnecting the service bus and connecting it again.*

*Reference:*

[Service bus explorer releases](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases)
[Microsoft blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/messaging-on-azure-blog/announcing-service-bus-explorer-for-azure-portal-public-preview/ba-p/3417168) by @Eldert Grootenboer.

Comment: This is a very old blog and the service bus explorer in the portal is not user friendly as the tool